# A new instance of timer created everytime I press a button

Tags: java, android, time

I am designing an incrementing clock, which will execute on button click and update the contents of the text view, as in time elapsed. But each time I press this button the previous clock is not getting cleared, a new instance starts and runs in parallel with the previous thread. I am unable to understand as in how do I stop this behavior of the same. Following is my code:

***Class level Variables:***

```
 int repeatCounter = 1;
 CountDownTimer tripTimeCounter;
```

================================================================================

```
  private View.OnClickListener but = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (isOnline() == true) {
            tripTimeCounter = new CountDownTimer(60 * 1000, 1000) {

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    repeatCounter = repeatCounter + 1;

                    this.start();
                    // startTimeCounter();
                }

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    timedisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                    timedisplay.setText(formatInterval((repeatCounter * 60)
                            * 1000 - millisUntilFinished));

                }

            }.start();
            tripTimeCounter.start();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Not connected to the internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: And what do you expect, if you on each click create new timer: tripTimeCounter = new CountDownTimer(60 * 1000, 1000)?

Comment: How do I cancel the old timer? That is what I am confused about!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html. check the cancel method

Comment: The confusing part: The calls to onTick(long) are synchronized to this object so that one call to onTick(long) won't ever occur before the previous callback is complete.

Comment: Why this `this.start()`?.

Comment: previously I had put it inside a function, but later on changed the code and introduced this, to check if the malfunction was occuring due to repeated function calls and each spawning a different thread.

Comment: At the class level @CodeMonkey, please refer to the Question above, the details are specified.

Answer (score 1):

Only skimmed this, but after Googling Timer, saw the [cancel](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#cancel%28%29) method, which says:

> When a timer is no longer needed, users should call cancel(), which releases the timer's thread and other resources. Timers not explicitly cancelled may hold resources indefinitely.

Comment: But where to call the Cancel? That is the question mate! Its all happening inside a button click!

Comment: Presumably right before the new creation, like so:

if(tripTimeCounter!=NULL)
 tripTimeCounter.cancel();
tripTimeCounter = new CountDownTimer(60 * 1000, 1000) {... etc.

Comment: Does work, only the seconds get reset. Another day of mind boggling!

Comment: Try tripTimeCounter.purge() right after and see if that clears it up.

Comment: The method purge() is undefined for the type CountDownTimer.

Comment: You are correct, sorry about that. What do you mean by only the seconds getting reset? Just so that I understand correctly.

Comment: Time Elapsed: 00:00:00(HH:MM:SS) after the above, if(tripTimeCounter!=NULL) tripTimeCounter.cancel(); Only the SS part seems to refresh.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34443/discussion-between-chucky-and-user2613996)